# Office365 GraphAPI Get Calendar Info for a specific day in Swift

Tags: swift, microsoft-graph-api

Hi there all you sexy people. I have a question how to get the calendar info for a specific day.

```
self.graphClient?.me()
    .calendarView()
    .event("?startDateTime=2016-01-01&endDateTime=2020-10-01")
    .request()
    .getWithCompletion({(graphEntity: MSGraphEntity?, error: Error?) in 
         //code
    })
```

This is the only way I figure out doing this. This doesn't work since the question-mark turn into `%3F`. But I think that it must be a better way to request this information since it's the API. Please help me you sexy people

Comment: Basicly my question is how to input querys into a request.

Comment: I solved it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var queryP1 = MSQueryParameters.init(key: "StartDateTime", value: "2016-01-20T09:00:00")
var queryP2 = MSQueryParameters.init(key: "EndDateTime", value: "2020-01-20T09:00:00")

    var queryArray = [Any]()
    queryArray.append(queryP1!)
    queryArray.append(queryP2!)

    _ = self.graphClient?.me().calendarView().request(withOptions: queryArray).getWithCompletion({ (col: MSCollection?, graphReq: MSGraphUserCalendarViewCollectionRequest?, error: Error?) in

        for calendarInfo: MSGraphEvent in col?.value as! [MSGraphEvent] {
            print(calendarInfo.subject)
        }

    })
```